Produce new line in XSLT 1.0 (where &#10; doesn't work)
I have this XSLT 1.0 template:
<xsl:template name="printDimHeader">
    <xsl:variable name="newline"><xsl:text>
    </xsl:text></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat('&quot;Dimensions&quot;: {', $newline)" />
</xsl:template>

Which is being called here:
<xsl:call-template name="printDimHeader">
    <xsl:with-param name="name" select="'Dimensions'"/>
</xsl:call-template>
<xsl:call-template name="Prop">
    <xsl:with-param name="key" select="'Width'"/>
    <xsl:with-param name="value" select="Properties/CabWidth"/>
</xsl:call-template>

and for some reason that I can't figure out, this is the result with the outputted file (JSON format):
"Dimensions": {              "Width": "600",

but they're supposed to be on separate lines. I've tried &#10; and &#xa; but no matter what I can't get it to put the "Width" on a new line.
Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
For reference, template printProp just strips units (mm) to return a plain number:
<xsl:template name="printProp">
    <xsl:param name="key"/>
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <xsl:variable name="clean" select="translate(normalize-space($value), '&quot;', '')"/>
    <xsl:if test="string-length($clean) > 0">
        <xsl:call-template name="printIndent">
            <xsl:with-param name="count" select="$extraIndent"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
        <xsl:text>"</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$key"/><xsl:text>": "</xsl:text><xsl:value-of select="$clean"/><xsl:text>"&#10;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>


Please provide a [mcve], not snippets of code taken out of context.

Use codepoints-to-string(10)

@Fravadona codepoints-to-string(10) is not available in XSLT 1.0 (not that it would produce anything other than &#10;).

@Fravadona &#10; is the literal line feed character, not just in XPath but in XML in general - see https://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#sec-references. Please do not take up this space with irrelevant arguments.

@Fravadona Where is there any mentioning of HTML in the linked dupe?

While asking an XSLT question you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) Well-formed input XML with all relevant namespaces.
(2) Your logic, and complete executable XSLT stylesheet that tries to implement it.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample XML in the #1 above.
(4) XSLT processor and its conformance with the XSLT standards: 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, or 4.0.
